# How to have object extend abstract class with generics

Tags: scala

I have the following abstract class:

```
abstract class MyList[A] {
  def head: A
  def tail: MyList[A]
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def add(element: A): MyList[A]
  def printElements: String
  override def toString: String = "[" + printElements + "]"
}
```

which I want to extend with an object representing the empty list:

```
object Empty extends MyList {
  def head = throw new NoSuchElementException
  def tail = throw new NoSuchElementException
  def isEmpty: Boolean = true
  def add(element: A): MyList[A] = new Cons(element, Empty)
  def printElements: String = ""
}
```

But I don't know how to reach the class parameter `A` properly from inside of `Empty`. Right now I get an error because the symbol A is not defined inside of `Empty`. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You find a similar example [here](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/functional-programming-in-scala/chapter-3/8)... you should take attention to generic type (co)variance and (maybe) move `add` method (do you mean `concat`?) to companion object, but the linked example can help you toward the solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty case for `A` should be the bottom type, called `Nothing` in Scala:

```
object Empty extends MyList[Nothing]
```

With that said, we'd still need to make a few modifications to the implementations in order for things to compile. First, we'd need to make `A` covariant in it's type parameter (more on that soon):

```
abstract class MyList[+A]
class Cons[+A](val head: A, val tail: MyList[A]) extends MyList[A]
```

For `add`, we'd need to create a [lower bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/lower-type-bounds.html) on `A` in order to allow any supertype to be valid (remember, `Nothing` "inherits" all types in Scala as it is the bottom type):

```
def add[B >: A](element: B): MyList[B]
```

And now we can implement `Empty`:

```
object Empty extends MyList[Nothing] {
  override def head: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException

  override def tail: MyList[Nothing] = throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No tail for empty list")

  override def isEmpty: Boolean = true

  override def printElements: String = ""

  override def add[B >: Nothing](element: B): MyList[B] = new Cons[B](element, Empty)
}
```

Since `add` requires us to create a new list, we have to make sure `Cons` accept `Empty` as a valid subtype. In order for us to preserve the "is subtype of" relation between `MyList` and `Empty`, the type must be marked as covariant.

Comment: I'd love to correct my answer if the downvoter would explain the problem.

Comment: And if a TS really would prefer to have `MyList` invariant then he should replace `object Empty extends MyList[Nothing]` with `class Empty[A] extends MyList[A]` and there will be different types `Empty[A]` for every type `A`.

Comment: There is no need to specify `Nothing` in any of the places where you put it, and there is no need to add unnecessary `override` declarations to the OPs original code.

Comment: @Tim I'd rather be explicit and explain "why" rather then leave it to fragile compiler implementation detail. Also, `override` was added by default when I implemented the version in IDEA ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It is not a compiler implementation detail, it is the language specification.

Comment: @Tim Where? I can't find it under type parameters: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#type-parameters

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Three out of four of the `Nothing` declarations that you added are clearly part of the language. But the point I am making is that it is best to leave as much of the OP code unchanged so that it is clear which changes actually matter.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a version of your code with the minimum modifications needed to make it work, plus an implementation of `Cons` that is required to make this compile:

```
abstract class MyList[+A] { // Added covariance
  def head: A
  def tail: MyList[A]
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def add[B >: A](element: B): MyList[B] // Added second type parameter
  def printElements: String
  override def toString: String = "[" + printElements + "]"
}

// Added implementation of Cons
class Cons[+A](val head: A, val tail: MyList[A]) extends MyList[A] {
  self =>
  val isEmpty = false
  def printElements = ...
  def add[B >: A](element: B): MyList[B] = new Cons(element, self)
}

object Empty extends MyList {
  def head = throw new NoSuchElementException
  def tail = throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No tail for empty list")
  def isEmpty: Boolean = true
  def printElements: String = ""
  def add[A](element: A): MyList[A] = new Cons(element, Empty) // Added type parameter
}
```